# how can I achieve in Maven 'fan out complexity' rule with PMD static analysis tool

Tags: static-analysis, checkstyle, pmd

I am new to PMD tool with Maven, I have to define rules for some Cyclic Complexity, Fan Out Complexity, and Depth in method.

I found solution for Cyclic Complexity,  and Depth in method but i am not able to find direct rule class for Fan Out Complexity, please give me suggestion to achieve it.

Comment: How does this relate to [tag:firebug]?

Answer (score 0):

Since you added the [checkstyle](/questions/tagged/checkstyle) tag to your question, you might be interested to know that there is a [fan out complexity check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_metrics.html#ClassFanOutComplexity) for Checkstyle. For PMD, I wouldn't know of such a check.